# List modification in recursive function calls

Tags: python, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have two simple recursive functions in Python as follows:

```
def test_list(outcome=[1]):
    outcome += [2*outcome[-1]]
    print(outcome)
    if outcome[-1] < 8:
        test_list(outcome)
    print(outcome)
```

```
def test_integer(n=1):
    n *= 2
    print(n)
    if n < 8:
        test_integer(n)
    print(n)
```

- “test_integer()” takes integer “n” as input, doubles its value, prints its value, recursively calls itself, and finally prints the value of “n” again. The outcome is expectedly as follows:

```text
    2
    4
    8
    8
    4
    2
```

Kowing the fact that subsequent doublings do not affect the value of the variable in the preceding recursions, I understand why the overall outcome of the function peaks at 8 and then drops to 2.

- “test_list()” works similar to “test_integer()” but after each doubling it appends the new value of “n” to a list  and then passes the list as input to the subsequent recursion. In this case, the overall outcome is different from what I expected. It seems that each time a new value is appended to the list it does affect the content of the list in the preceding recursions. More specifically, I expected the outcome to be:

```text
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2]
```

But in reality, it is:

```text
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
[1, 2, 4, 8]
```

Any hints why these two functions behave differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, an augmented assignment like `x += y` is an alias for `x = x + y`, which creates a new value and binds it with the left argument.

However, the list class redefines `+=` in a special way, so that it directly mutates the left argument instead of assigning to it. If you want the new value semantics, you have to use the plain assignment `outcome = outcome + ...`.

Illustration:

```
old_a = a = [1, 2]
a += [99] # <- mutation
print(old_a, a)  # [1, 2, 99] [1, 2, 99]

old_b = b = [1, 2]
b = b + [99] # <- new value
print(old_b, b)  # [1, 2] [1, 2, 99]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `n` in `test_integer` is a local variable. initialized by the value you pass when invoking a function, so each recursive `test_integer` execution has its own copy of `n`.

OTOH, `outcome` in `test_list` is a list passed by a reference, so you append a doubled value to the *original array*, and it's never stripped back. As a result, on the return from recursion you have the same expanded array on each level.

Comment: For a certain application I need "test_list" to behave like "test_integer". How can I pass a separate copy of the original array to each recursion so that the modification done in each recursion would not affect the others?

Comment: @Alex This is quite a different topic. Your question is _'**Why** does **this** code work **this** way?'_ while your comment is _'**How** to make a code to work **that** way?'_ and I'd suggest to ask the latter as a separate question.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "passing by reference", whatever you mean by that.